# Load sqlite store with swift

Tags: sqlite, core-data, swift, xcode6.1

I'd like to load a sqlite store, which if added to my Project in Xcode. I know how to do it in Objective-C but I'm still learning Swift. I tried it in Swift but had no success.
Does someone knows how I could do this in Swift?

My Code for deleting:

```
   var daten = [Notizen]()
   let context = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate).managedObjectContext


func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> Bool {
    return true
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete) {
        // handle delete (by removing the data from your array and updating the tableview)


        if let tv=tableView
        {

            context?.deleteObject(daten[indexPath.row])
            context?.save(nil)
            let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Notizen")
            daten = context?.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: nil) as [Notizen]
            tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Right)

        }
    }
}
```

Crash log:

`2014-12-16 17:48:17.197 NoteApp[3161:45746] CoreData: error: failed to resolve optimistic locking failure: optimistic locking failure with (null)
2014-12-16 17:48:17.197 NoteApp[3161:45746] CoreData: error: failed to resolve optimistic locking failure.  Old save request was: <NSSaveChangesRequest: 0x7a6c9270> { inserts (), updates (), deletes ((
    "0x7b862ec0 <x-coredata://21112FCF-88DE-4D7F-A5C5-1A97731D180E/Notizen/p2>"
)) locks () }
2014-12-16 17:48:17.198 NoteApp[3161:45746] CoreData: error: failed to resolve optimistic locking failure.  Next attempt will be: <NSSaveChangesRequest: 0x7a6c9270> { inserts (), updates (), deletes ((
    "0x7b862ec0 <x-coredata://21112FCF-88DE-4D7F-A5C5-1A97731D180E/Notizen/p2>"
)) locks () }
2014-12-16 17:48:17.198 NoteApp[3161:45746] CoreData: sql: BEGIN EXCLUSIVE
2014-12-16 17:48:17.198 NoteApp[3161:45746] CoreData: sql: DELETE FROM ZNOTIZEN WHERE Z_PK = ? AND Z_OPT = ?
2014-12-16 17:48:17.198 NoteApp[3161:45746] CoreData: details: SQLite bind[0] = (int64)2
2014-12-16 17:48:17.198 NoteApp[3161:45746] CoreData: details: SQLite bind[1] = nil
2014-12-16 17:48:17.199 NoteApp[3161:45746] CoreData: sql: ROLLBACK
2014-12-16 17:48:17.199 NoteApp[3161:45746] CoreData: sql: SELECT Z_PK,Z_OPT FROM ZNOTIZEN WHERE Z_PK IN (2) ORDER BY Z_PK
2014-12-16 17:48:17.199 NoteApp[3161:45746] CoreData: annotation: sql execution time: 0.0002s
2014-12-16 17:48:17.199 NoteApp[3161:45746] CoreData: error: failed to resolve optimistic locking failure: optimistic locking failure with (null)
2014-12-16 17:48:17.211 NoteApp[3161:45746] CoreData: error: failed to resolve optimistic locking failure.  Old save request was: <NSSaveChangesRequest: 0x7a6c9270> { inserts (), updates (), deletes ((
    "0x7b862ec0 <x-coredata://21112FCF-88DE-4D7F-A5C5-1A97731D180E/Notizen/p2>"
)) locks () }
2014-12-16 17:48:17.211 NoteApp[3161:45746] CoreData: error: failed to resolve optimistic locking failure.  Next attempt will be: <NSSaveChangesRequest: 0x7a6c9270> { inserts (), updates (), deletes ((
    "0x7b862ec0 <x-coredata://21112FCF-88DE-4D7F-A5C5-1A97731D180E/Notizen/p2>"
)) locks () }
2014-12-16 17:48:17.212 NoteApp[3161:45746] CoreData: sql: BEGIN EXCLUSIVE
2014-12-16 17:48:17.212 NoteApp[3161:45746] CoreData: sql: DELETE FROM ZNOTIZEN WHERE Z_PK = ? AND Z_OPT = ?
2014-12-16 17:48:17.212 NoteApp[3161:45746] CoreData: details: SQLite bind[0] = (int64)2
2014-12-16 17:48:17.212 NoteApp[3161:45746] CoreData: details: SQLite bind[1] = nil
2014-12-16 17:48:17.213 NoteApp[3161:45746] CoreData: sql: ROLLBACK
2014-12-16 17:48:17.213 NoteApp[3161:45746] CoreData: sql: SELECT Z_PK,Z_OPT FROM ZNOTIZEN WHERE Z_PK IN (2) ORDER BY Z_PK
2014-12-16 17:48:17.213 NoteApp[3161:45746] CoreData: annotation: sql execution time: 0.0003s
2014-12-16 17:48:17.214 NoteApp[3161:45746] CoreData: error: failed to resolve optimistic locking failure: optimistic locking failure with (null)
2014-12-16 17:48:17.214 NoteApp[3161:45746] CoreData: error: failed to resolve optimistic locking failure.  Old save request was: <NSSaveChangesRequest: 0x7a6c9270> { inserts (), updates (), deletes ((
    "0x7b862ec0 <x-coredata://21112FCF-88DE-4D7F-A5C5-1A97731D180E/Notizen/p2>"
)) locks () }
2014-12-16 17:48:17.214 NoteApp[3161:45746] CoreData: error: failed to resolve optimistic locking failure.  Next attempt will be: <NSSaveChangesRequest: 0x7a6c9270> { inserts (), updates (), deletes ((
    "0x7b862ec0 <x-coredata://21112FCF-88DE-4D7F-A5C5-1A97731D180E/Notizen/p2>"
)) locks () }
2014-12-16 17:48:17.214 NoteApp[3161:45746] CoreData: sql: BEGIN EXCLUSIVE
2014-12-16 17:48:17.214 NoteApp[3161:45746] CoreData: sql: DELETE FROM ZNOTIZEN WHERE Z_PK = ? AND Z_OPT = ?
2014-12-16 17:48:17.215 NoteApp[3161:45746] CoreData: details: SQLite bind[0] = (int64)2
2014-12-16 17:48:17.215 NoteApp[3161:45746] CoreData: details: SQLite bind[1] = nil
2014-12-16 17:48:17.215 NoteApp[3161:45746] CoreData: sql: ROLLBACK
2014-12-16 17:48:17.215 NoteApp[3161:45746] CoreData: sql: SELECT Z_PK,Z_OPT FROM ZNOTIZEN WHERE Z_PK IN (2) ORDER BY Z_PK
2014-12-16 17:48:17.215 NoteApp[3161:45746] CoreData: annotation: sql execution time: 0.0003s
2014-12-16 17:48:17.216 NoteApp[3161:45746] CoreData: error: failed to resolve optimistic locking failure: optimistic locking failure with (null)
2014-12-16 17:48:17.216 NoteApp[3161:45746] CoreData: error: failed to resolve optimistic locking failure.  Old save request was: <NSSaveChangesRequest: 0x7a6c9270> { inserts (), updates (), deletes ((
    "0x7b862ec0 <x-coredata://21112FCF-88DE-4D7F-A5C5-1A97731D180E/Notizen/p2>"
)) locks () }
2014-12-16 17:48:17.216 NoteApp[3161:45746] CoreData: error: failed to resolve optimistic locking failure.  Next attempt will be: <NSSaveChangesRequest: 0x7a6c9270> { inserts (), updates (), deletes ((
    "0x7b862ec0 <x-coredata://21112FCF-88DE-4D7F-A5C5-1A97731D180E/Notizen/p2>"
)) locks () }
2014-12-16 17:48:17.216 NoteApp[3161:45746] CoreData: sql: BEGIN EXCLUSIVE
2014-12-16 17:48:17.217 NoteApp[3161:45746] CoreData: sql: DELETE FROM ZNOTIZEN WHERE Z_PK = ? AND Z_OPT = ?
2014-12-16 17:48:17.217 NoteApp[3161:45746] CoreData: details: SQLite bind[0] = (int64)2
2014-12-16 17:48:17.217 NoteApp[3161:45746] CoreData: details: SQLite bind[1] = nil
2014-12-16 17:48:17.217 NoteApp[3161:45746] CoreData: sql: ROLLBACK
2014-12-16 17:48:17.217 NoteApp[3161:45746] CoreData: sql: SELECT Z_PK,Z_OPT FROM ZNOTIZEN WHERE Z_PK IN (2) ORDER BY Z_PK
2014-12-16 17:48:17.218 NoteApp[3161:45746] CoreData: annotation: sql execution time: 0.0003s
2014-12-16 17:48:17.218 NoteApp[3161:45746] CoreData: error: failed to resolve optimistic locking failure: optimistic locking failure with (null)
2014-12-16 17:48:17.218 NoteApp[3161:45746] CoreData: error: failed to resolve optimistic locking failure.  Old save request was: <NSSaveChangesRequest: 0x7a6c9270> { inserts (), updates (), deletes ((
    "0x7b862ec0 <x-coredata://21112FCF-88DE-4D7F-A5C5-1A97731D180E/Notizen/p2>"
)) locks () }
2014-12-16 17:48:17.218 NoteApp[3161:45746] CoreData: error: failed to resolve optimistic locking failure.  Next attempt will be: <NSSaveChangesRequest: 0x7b89bda0> { inserts (), updates (), deletes ((
    "0x7b862ec0 <x-coredata://21112FCF-88DE-4D7F-A5C5-1A97731D180E/Notizen/p2>"
)) locks () }
2014-12-16 17:48:17.219 NoteApp[3161:45746] CoreData: sql: BEGIN EXCLUSIVE
2014-12-16 17:48:17.219 NoteApp[3161:45746] CoreData: sql: DELETE FROM ZNOTIZEN WHERE Z_PK = ? AND Z_OPT = ?
2014-12-16 17:48:17.219 NoteApp[3161:45746] CoreData: details: SQLite bind[0] = (int64)2
2014-12-16 17:48:17.219 NoteApp[3161:45746] CoreData: details: SQLite bind[1] = nil
2014-12-16 17:48:17.219 NoteApp[3161:45746] CoreData: sql: ROLLBACK
2014-12-16 17:48:17.220 NoteApp[3161:45746] CoreData: sql: SELECT Z_PK,Z_OPT FROM ZNOTIZEN WHERE Z_PK IN (2) ORDER BY Z_PK
2014-12-16 17:48:17.220 NoteApp[3161:45746] CoreData: annotation: sql execution time: 0.0003s
2014-12-16 17:48:17.220 NoteApp[3161:45746] CoreData: error: failed to resolve optimistic locking failure: optimistic locking failure with (null)
2014-12-16 17:48:17.220 NoteApp[3161:45746] CoreData: error: failed to resolve optimistic locking failure.  Old save request was: <NSSaveChangesRequest: 0x7b89bda0> { inserts (), updates (), deletes ((
    "0x7b862ec0 <x-coredata://21112FCF-88DE-4D7F-A5C5-1A97731D180E/Notizen/p2>"
)) locks () }
2014-12-16 17:48:17.221 NoteApp[3161:45746] CoreData: error: failed to resolve optimistic locking failure.  Next attempt will be: <NSSaveChangesRequest: 0x7b89bda0> { inserts (), updates (), deletes ((
    "0x7b862ec0 <x-coredata://21112FCF-88DE-4D7F-A5C5-1A97731D180E/Notizen/p2>"
)) locks () }
2014-12-16 17:48:17.221 NoteApp[3161:45746] CoreData: error: fatal: Unable to recover from optimistic locking failure.
(lldb)`

Comment: Show your code so far, with details of errors.

Comment: I didn't get it converted to Swift.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place this in the AppDelegate.  And make sure the NameOfFile.sqlite is in the project and being copied.

```
lazy var persistentStoreCoordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator? = {
    // The persistent store coordinator for the application. This implementation creates and return a coordinator, having added the store for the application to it. This property is optional since there are legitimate error conditions that could cause the creation of the store to fail.
    // Create the coordinator and store
    var coordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator? = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: self.managedObjectModel)
    let url = self.applicationDocumentsDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent("NameOfFile.sqlite")
    var error: NSError? = nil
    var failureReason = "There was an error creating or loading the application's saved data."
    // Copying
    let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("NameOfFile", ofType:"sqlite")!

    NSFileManager.defaultManager().copyItemAtPath(path, toPath: url.path!, error:nil)
    if coordinator!.addPersistentStoreWithType(NSSQLiteStoreType, configuration: nil, URL: NSURL.fileURLWithPath(url.path!), options: nil, error: &error) == nil {
        coordinator = nil
        // Report any error we got.
        let dict = NSMutableDictionary()
        dict[NSLocalizedDescriptionKey] = "Failed to initialize the application's saved data"
        dict[NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey] = failureReason
        dict[NSUnderlyingErrorKey] = error
        //error = NSError.errorWithDomain("YOUR_ERROR_DOMAIN", code: 9999, userInfo: dict)
        // Replace this with code to handle the error appropriately.
        // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
        NSLog("Unresolved error \(error), \(error!.userInfo)")
        abort()
    }

    return coordinator
}()
```

It looks like you may have things out of order. Also I have a different approach so hope this helps.

```
    // called when a row deletion action is confirmed
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        switch editingStyle {
        case .Delete:
            // remove the deleted item from the model
            let appDel:AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
            let context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!
            context.deleteObject(myData[indexPath.row] as NSManagedObject)
            myData.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
            context.save(nil)

           //tableView.reloadData()
            // remove the deleted item from the `UITableView`
            self.tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
        default:
            return

        }
}
```

Comment: Make sure you delete the app on your test device before running with this code. Also that you have the file in the project. I have mine in supporting files and make sure it is being copied in build phases - copy bundle resources. How did you create and populate the sqlite file?

Comment: I have also my .sqlite file in the supporting files folder. Yes, it's copied in copy bundle resources. I created my file by running my app and saving (typing in) the data which I want to use as default data / data which should be shown if the app is first time opened. After this I copied the AppName.sqlite file into my app and have done the steps which you described.

Comment: I use Valentina Studio edit my sqlite files. I run the app once in the simulator then copy the created sqlite file out and edit file and added the correct data, then copy it to my project. Which sounds like you have done the same. If I need to make any changes I just then edit the file in the project folder.  Then one thing I forgot some times is to delete the app in the simulator or on the device so the new sqlite file dose not copy because one already exist.

Comment: Ok. Then I'll try it also with Valentina Studio but I don't know how I can add data into the file. Could you please help me to do this?

Comment: You have to add the path of the sqlite file to the program which it will prompt you for when try to open the file the first time. Then once you have the sqlite file open. select the table you want add information to then select open data editor. Keep in mind you Z_PK has to be unique and Z_ENT should match the value found in Z_PRIMARYKEY table. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! I get it. But if I run my app and would like to edit the data (delete) the app is crashing. By the way the data is placed into a UITableView. And it also works only if the name of the sqlite file isn't the same as the app name. If it's the same name it's not working / I can't see the data.

Comment: Ok the sqlite file name has to match the xcdatamodel name. I would have to see the code you are using for the delete.

Comment: The app crashes in this line of code: `context.save(nil)` the crash log is updated in my question.

Comment: That could mean that you have something wrong in the sqlite file that you are copying. Try commenting to the two lines that do the copy of the sqlite file and make sure to delete the app in simulator or on device then run with a blank core data and see if it still happens. Remember if you make any changes to core data you will need to run the app with a blank database then copy the new sqlite file back out form the simulator and replace the one in your project.

Comment: It's not working. Do you have Skype? I think it's easier to solve it via Skype. Of course I'll post the solution here.

Comment: Sorry traveling for the holidays and no Skype. Has any thing changed?

Comment: I did it on an other way. I used NSUserDefaults to find out if the app launched first time. If yes, I added a function, which adds my data into the tableView.